# The "OpenStack" package ignores system-wide network proxy settings

Tags: juju, proxy, maas, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I often found myself redownloading the same package of lxc instances when failed and retried to reinstall the openstack-install either using the Landscape, single, or multi modes options, which take time on slow connection. Juju bootstrapping does not obey the system-wide proxy when downloading the packages, instances, and/or lxc containers it needs. Fortunately, the MaaS installation is now set up manually so we can define MAAS_HTTP_PROXY within the MAAS GUI.

I've setup the /etc/environment, /etc/apt/apt.conf, and /etc/wgetrc to use proxy server in local network but the tool ignores the setting and goes right through the internet each time it's reinstalled or redeployed.

How can I configure the openstack-install to obey system-wide network proxy setting so all the download packages, instances, and containers be cached in squid for easier and faster deployment?

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking about the Cloud Installer, and not the OpenStack Autopilot, right? OSA is the one inside Landscape.

Comment: Hi @andreas, I'm talking about the Ubuntu OpenStack Cloud Installer which includes MaaS, Juju, OpenStack, and Landscape. I believe I saw the post in G+ stream as OpenStack Autopilot though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about all the downloads that you are seeing but at least lxc images are retrieved over HTTPS so will not be cacheable.

See: https://www.mail-archive.com/juju@lists.ubuntu.com/msg01303.html

Comment: oh that's why the lxc containers is not cached. thanks for the info. :)

Answer (score 1):

The installer sets `apt-http-proxy` to whatever your MAAS server IP is for an existing MAAS installation. So whenever juju deploys any services which require apt-get installs it'll pull from that proxy.

Comment: thanks for the comment. I didn't have problems with the apt packages, they were all retrieved from the squid box, but the lxc containers which juju bootstraps does not.